# REG DELETE command is not working on 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry

I'm using command below to delete a simple registry key which is not protected, I mean you can easily delete it using regedit GUI, so the permission is free and unlocked.

```
reg delete TargetKEY /f
```

This command will work fine in 32 bit system, but on 64 bit OS it gives me "access is denied" as long as there is no limitation with target key's permission rules.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you running this command as an administrator?

Comment: As long as I am the ADMINISTRATOR so it should run as an administrator ;)

Comment: Nope, even if you are administrator you still have to run it as administrator :) I mean even if you are using local administrator account, STILL, you have to do that to elevate that process. Try it yourself and see if there's a difference.

Comment: There is a Bat file contains this command and it is going to be launched by another application, So I have no choice to do it by my own hands :( The strange part is that it is working fine on x86 OS and this error is shown only on x64 OS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are not running the command as an administrator in 64 BIT OS. Look at this:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

This command ran within the local administrator account. Now look at this:

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

See the difference?

So, from the comments, if this command running within another batch file, you should run that batch file as an administrator since it will pass authorization to this command. Also you can try disabling UAC.

Comment: Yes It seems It is working if I run it as administrator, But the problem is that I should do it with my hands! The command is running by an application so is there any extra command to add before reg delete to force it running as administrator?

Comment: you can use runas. for example: runas /u:username password "reg delete bla bla /f"